# Static Function using static variable error (illegal reference)

Tags: c++, glfw

Ive been working in glfw c++ and want to get input from the mouse wheel by using the glfwSetScrollCallback() and I put it in a window class that I created because it requires a glfw window. I created a scroll_callback function that adjusts the fov for the camera that I initialize in a camera class. The glfwSetScrollCallback() uses that static void of my scroll_callback function in my camera class. However, I cant seem how to initialize a the fov variable in my camera.h and use it in the static void in my camera.cpp. I tried changing it to a static public variable because I need to call it in my main class but it didnt work. Any thoughts thank you!!!

camera.h

```
#pragma once

#include <GL\glew.h>

#include <glm\glm.hpp>
#include <glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp>

#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

class Camera
{


public:
    Camera();
    Camera(glm::vec3 startPosition, glm::vec3 startUp, GLfloat startYaw, GLfloat startPitch, GLfloat startMoveSpeed, GLfloat startTurnSpeed);

    void keyControl(bool* keys, GLfloat deltaTime);
    void mouseControl(GLfloat xChange, GLfloat yChange);

    static float fov;

    glm::mat4 calculateViewMatrix();

    ~Camera();

    static void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);

private:
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 front;
    glm::vec3 up;
    glm::vec3 right;
    glm::vec3 worldUp;

    GLfloat yaw;
    GLfloat pitch;

    GLfloat moveSpeed;
    GLfloat turnSpeed;



    void update();
};
```

Camera.cpp

```
#include "Camera.h"
#include <iostream>

Camera::Camera() {}

Camera::Camera(glm::vec3 startPosition, glm::vec3 startUp, GLfloat startYaw, GLfloat startPitch, GLfloat startMoveSpeed, GLfloat startTurnSpeed)
{
    position = startPosition;
    worldUp = startUp;
    yaw = startYaw;
    pitch = startPitch;
    front = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);

    moveSpeed = startMoveSpeed;
    turnSpeed = startTurnSpeed;

    update();
}

void Camera::keyControl(bool* keys, GLfloat deltaTime)
{
    GLfloat velocity = moveSpeed * deltaTime;

    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_W] || keys[GLFW_KEY_UP])
    {
        position += front * velocity;
    }

    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_S] || keys[GLFW_KEY_DOWN])
    {
        position -= front * velocity;
    }

    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_A] || keys[GLFW_KEY_LEFT])
    {
        position -= right * velocity;
    }

    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_D] || keys[GLFW_KEY_RIGHT])
    {
        position += right * velocity;
    }
}



void Camera::mouseControl(GLfloat xChange, GLfloat yChange)
{
    xChange *= turnSpeed;
    yChange *= turnSpeed;

    yaw += xChange;

    pitch += yChange;

    if (pitch > 89.0f)
    {
        pitch = 89.0f;
    }

    if (pitch < -89.0f)
    {
        pitch = -89.0f;
    }

    update();
}



void Camera::scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{

    if (fov > 1.0f && fov < 45.0f)
        fov -= yoffset;
    else if (fov <= 1.0f)
        fov = 1.0f;
    else if (fov >= 45.0f)
        fov = 45.0f;

}


glm::mat4 Camera::calculateViewMatrix()
{
    return glm::lookAt(position, position + front, up);
}

void Camera::update()
{
    front.x = cos(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.y = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.z = sin(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    front = glm::normalize(front);

    right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(front, worldUp));
    up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(right, front));
}


Camera::~Camera()
{
}
```

window.cpp

```
#include "Window.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include <iostream>


Window::Window()
{
    width = 800;
    height = 800;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    {
        keys[i] = 0;
    }
}

Window::Window(GLint windowWidth, GLint windowHeight)
{
    width = windowWidth;
    height = windowHeight;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    {
        keys[i] = 0;
    }
}

int Window::Initialise()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        printf("Error Initialising GLFW");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }



    // Setup GLFW Windows Properties
    // OpenGL version
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    // Core Profile
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    // Allow forward compatiblity
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);




    // Create the window
    mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Test Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (!mainWindow)
    {
        printf("Error creating GLFW window!");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Get buffer size information
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(mainWindow, &bufferWidth, &bufferHeight);

    // Set the current context
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(mainWindow);

    // Handle Key + Mouse Input
    createCallbacks();
    glfwSetScrollCallback(mainWindow, Camera::scroll_callback);
    glfwSetInputMode(mainWindow, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // Allow modern extension access
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;



    GLenum error = glewInit();
    if (error != GLEW_OK)
    {
        printf("Error: %s", glewGetErrorString(error));
        glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow);
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Create Viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);

    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(mainWindow, this);

}

void Window::createCallbacks()
{
    glfwSetKeyCallback(mainWindow, handleKeys);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(mainWindow, handleMouse);

}

GLfloat Window::getXChange()
{
    GLfloat theChange = xChange;
    xChange = 0.0f;
    return theChange;
}

GLfloat Window::getYChange()
{
    GLfloat theChange = yChange;
    yChange = 0.0f;
    return theChange;
}



void Window::handleKeys(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int code, int action, int mode)
{
    Window* theWindow = static_cast<Window*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {

        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }

    if (key >= 0 && key < 1024)
    {
        if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            theWindow->keys[key] = true;
        }
        else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        {
            theWindow->keys[key] = false;
        }
    }
}




void Window::handleMouse(GLFWwindow* window, double xPos, double yPos)
{
    Window* theWindow = static_cast<Window*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));

    if (theWindow->mouseFirstMoved)
    {
        theWindow->lastX = xPos;
        theWindow->lastY = yPos;
        theWindow->mouseFirstMoved = false;
    }

    theWindow->xChange = xPos - theWindow->lastX;
    theWindow->yChange = theWindow->lastY - yPos;

    theWindow->lastX = xPos;
    theWindow->lastY = yPos;
}

Window::~Window()
{
    glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Comment: In Camera.cpp, try putting (before any code, but after includes) `float Camera::fov = 0.f` I'm assuming it just hasnt been allocated space yet. After that, you should be able to use it like normal.

Comment: Yep [static members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

Comment: Yep that worked out thank you!!!